# Magento2: New Customer grid column breaks the export functionality

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, export, customer-attribute, customer-grid

I am working on a Magento2 extension. I added a column called "exported_to_stannp" to my customer grid using the following code:

**app\code\Namespace\Module\Setup\InstallData.php**

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Type;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, SetFactory $attributeSetFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup'=>$setup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'exported_to_stannp');

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(Customer::ENTITY);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY, 'exported_to_stannp', [
//                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => \Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute\Backend\Data\Boolean::class,
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Exported to Stannp',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'adminhtml_only' => true,
                'default' => 0,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'value' => 0,
                'is_used_in_customer_segment' => true,
                "is_used_in_grid" => true,
                "is_visible_in_grid" => true,
                "is_filterable_in_grid" => true,
                "is_searchable_in_grid" => false
        ]
        );

        $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'exported_to_stannp')
            ->addData(
                [
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']
                ]
            )->save();


        $installer->endSetup();
    }

}
```

**app\code\Namespace\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="customer_columns">
    <column name="exported_to_stannp">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Exported to Stannp</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">166</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
</listing>
```

**app\code\Namespace\Module\etc\indexer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
    <indexer id="customer_grid">
        <fieldset name="customer" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\AttributeProvider">
            <field name="exported_to_stannp" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="int"/>
        </fieldset>
    </indexer>
</config>
```

Everything works fine, except for the export functionality in grid. I get the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Users/iunia/Sites/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 213 and defined in /Users/iunia/Sites/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 164
```

I put logs in 2 files: 
**vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php** line 212 $rawComponentData
and
**vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php** line 73 $this->getName() and $dataType.

```
/Users/iunia/Sites/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php:73:string 'exported_to_stannp' (length=18)
/Users/iunia/Sites/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php:74:string 'select' (length=6) /Users/iunia/Sites/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:212:
array (size=4)
  'arguments' => 
    array (size=1)
      'data' => 
        array (size=1)
          'config' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
  'attributes' => 
    array (size=3)
      'class' => string 'Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select' (length=40)
      'component' => string 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select' (length=33)
      'template' => string 'ui/form/field' (length=13)
  'children' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'uiComponentType' => string 'select' (length=6)

/Users/iunia/Sites/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php:73:string 'exported_to_stannp' (length=18)
/Users/iunia/Sites/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php:74:string 'varchar' (length=7)
/Users/iunia/Sites/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:212:null
```

If I add the ($this->getName() != 'exported_to_stannp') to the condition at line 74, it works as expected.

$dataType is null the second time in the logs, and only for any export.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out/removing the following code fixed my problem. I still have to test it on a fresh install, but for now it seems to be working.

**app\code\Namespace\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\customer_listing.xml**

```
<columns name="customer_columns">
    <column name="exported_to_stannp">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Exported to Stannp</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">166</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Comment: Yes, but this removes your custom column as well.

Comment: It didn't, for me. It works perfectly.